# Recursive search for element part of XmlSchemaDocument

Tags: c#, loops, xsd, out-of-memory, xmldocument

In the code below, I am searching for an element in an XmlSchemaDocument. The iteration works just fine if the element is part of the XmlSchemaDocument.

```
 public void FindSchemaElement(string elementName, string dataType, List<XmlSchemaElement> allChildren, string parentName)
    {
        try
        {
            List<XmlSchemaElement> temp = new List<XmlSchemaElement>();
            temp.AddRange(allChildren);
            foreach (XmlSchemaElement e in allChildren)
            {
                if (e.Name != elementName && e.RefName.Name != elementName &&
                    (dataType == "" || e.SchemaTypeName.Name != dataType)) continue;
                if (e.Parent == null || e.Parent is XmlSchema)
                {
                    ElementToBeFound = e;
                    return;
                }
                var parent = e.Parent;
                while (parent != null && parent.GetType() != typeof(XmlSchemaElement))
                    parent = parent.Parent;

                if (parent != null && ((XmlSchemaElement) parent).Name == parentName)
                {
                    ElementToBeFound = e;
                    return;
                }
                if (parent == null || parent.GetType() == typeof(XmlSchema)) ElementToBeFound = e;
            }
            if (ElementToBeFound != null) return;
            _childrenList.Clear();
            if (temp.Count > 0)
                GetNextChildren(temp, dataType, elementName, parentName);
        }
        catch(Exception exception){Debug.WriteLine("FindSchemaElement: "+exception.Message);}
    }
```

Getting the children:

```
private void GetNextChildren(List<XmlSchemaElement> allChildren, string dataType, string elementName, string parentName = "")
        {
            try
            {
                foreach (XmlSchemaElement e in allChildren)
                    GetChildren(e);
                if (parentName != string.Empty)
                    FindSchemaElement(elementName, dataType, _childrenList, parentName);
                else
                    FindSubsGroups(elementName, dataType, _childrenList);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            { Debug.WriteLine("GetNextChildren: " + ex.Message); }
        }
```

In GetChildren() - I am just checking the type of the element (sequence, choice element) and if it is an element, I am adding it to the _childrenList.

However, if the element cannot be found, I get stuck in a loop and I eventually run out of memory (the .xsd files that I am using are quite large).
I noticed that I have this issue only when, in the .xsd, there is a loop - as seen in the picture:
[image: xsd example]
Is there any way to stop the iteration when the element has not been found but there is such a loop?

Comment: There is the `break` Keyword in Loops for stopping iterations.

Comment: I know that.. But how do I know when the loop needs to be stopped? I need to make sure that all the elements have been checked and then I can stop the loop.

Comment: What does the function `GetChildren` and `FindSubsGroups`? Could you post them too?

Comment: In GetChildren() - I am just checking the type of the element (sequence, choice element) and if it is an element, I am adding it to the _childrenList.

Comment: For the subgroups, I am just getting the elements part of the same subgroup.

Comment: Out of interest what's the code for? If its just for a specific use case it may be OK, but you have no namespaces in your search criteria and you are also ignoring element groups and complex types that are valid if xsi:type is used in the output XML

Comment: I am reading an xsd and getting the possible children and attributes of an element. The code is part of a tool to create an XML file based on an XSD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to keep track of what you've already searched.
Then GetNextChildren can check and if its already processed that element it can ignore it. The call to it from your main function should pass in a new HashSet

```
GetNextChildren(new HashSet<XmlSchemaElement>(), ....);
```

Your codes a bit all over the place so I've just done the bit that prevents infinite recursion.

```
   private void GetNextChildren(HashSet<XmlSchemaElement> searchedElements, List<XmlSchemaElement> allChildren, string dataType, string elementName, string parentName = "")
    {
        try
        {
            foreach (XmlSchemaElement e in allChildren)
            {
                if (searchedElements.Contains(e) == false)
                {
                    searchedElements.Add(e);

                   // Search for it
                   // GetNextChildren(searchedElements, ....);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        { Debug.WriteLine("GetNextChildren: " + ex.Message); }
    }
```

You should also note that schemas can include each other in a circular was as well (a.xsd includes b.xsd and b.xsd includes a.xsd). I think the same is also true for element group.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you for taking your time. I used your idea a bit differently. I created an external HashSet to store the items. Once i checked one item, I add it to the searchedElements list. When adding the new children to the list, I check it against the searchedElements list. If anyone is interested, I can post the update.